# Doubt with exponentials: Is it correct to write $2^n + 2^n = 2 \cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem with the first part of a problem. Is it correct to say that:

$$2^n + 2^n = 2 \cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1}$$

When one has:
$2^n + 2^n$ that is not the same as the line above, right? When you have $2\cdot 2^n$ that is the same as $2^{n+1}$. Am I right or my algebra is losing here?

The same base you sum the exponential. Right?

So it could no be that $2^n + 2^n = 2 \cdot 2^n$

I am confused about this.

Comment: The LHS is even while the RHS is odd. Obviously this is false. What is true is that $2^n + 2^n = 2 \times 2^n = 2^{n+1}$.

Comment: What you probably mean is that $2^n + 2^n = 2  \cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1}$

Comment: Maybe “The same base you sum the exponential” is your description of what happens when you *multiply* two powers with the same base: $2^a\times2^b=2^{a+b}$. When you add, there is no similar simplification.

Comment: Made a mistake when editing. I meant $2^{n+1}$

Comment: Didier, but how $2^n + 2^n = 2  x  2^n$. I learned as I said that the law was "The same base you sum the exponential" but only with multiplication? is that not right?

Comment: @GratefullyDead $2^n + 2^n = 2 \cdot 2^n$ is just $x + x = 2 x$.